# Jquery ajax call not working on android

Tags: javascript, php, android, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax calls I'm making cross domain using jsonp.
The code is:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://my-url.com/getSearchResults.php",
    data: { 
        userId: localUserId, 
        searchLocation: decodeURIComponent(searchLocation), 
        searchCategory: searchCategory 
    }
})
.done(function(items) {
    alert(items);
});
```

When I run this in a normal browser I get in the alert box [object object] as I should, but when I run it on an android mobile browser it returns a blank alert box.

My PHP contains headers to allow cross domain.

The actual resonse from the ajax call (the object) is something like this:

```
[{
    "address": "London Road, Brighton, United Kingdom",
    "details": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "kav 2",
        "logo": "user_content\/1167327737_images.jpg",
        "favorite": "0",
        "feedback": 0
    }   
}];
```

I am trying to find a solution for the past 3 days. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try adding an `.error` function? Maybe it will tell you more about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while but I found the solution.

Even though Ajax calls of datatype jsonp are always sent with $_GET no matter what you put in the type, With android browser, if you put in the type POST they will be sent as $_POST.

Once I changed the type to GET everything started working again.